# ¿Como hacer para que cuando le de en 1-efectivo me salga el precio total y cuando le 2-tarjeta le aplique el 5%? En c#

Tags: c#

Se trata sobre comida rapida, todo el codigo esta en un botón que se llama calcular precio total, y son 4 comidas y 4 bebidas, lo que quiero es que calcule el 5% si la persona ingrese el 2 en el textbox, el 2 es la tarjeta de crédito, y el 1 es el efectivo. El código no me agarra ya que al introducir en el textbox el 1 me sale en el precio total el numero 1, y así. No se como puedo hacer para que me funcione. Tambien quiero si la persona quiere agregar mas bebida o comida, que en la variable subtotal tiene que irse sumando lo anterior que eligio la persona y no se como hacerlo.

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tot = this.TXTET.Text; //esta es la variable para el precio total
        int TOT = int.Parse(tot);

        int STCR = 0; // esta es la variable para el subtotal de comida rapida
        int ST = 0;

        int POR = 005; // es el porcentaje que se le aplicara si la persona elige tarjeta


        string NUM1 = this.TXTCR.Text;
        int CR = int.Parse(NUM1); // esta es para el textbox donde introduzco el numero del 1 al 8(comida y bebida)

        string NUM = this.TXTCCR.Text;
        int CCR = Int16.Parse(NUM); //es para indroducir la cantidad de comida

        var RES = this.TXTRESP.Text; //es para agregar mas comida

        while (RES == "SI") 
        {
            this.TXTRESP.Enabled = true;

            switch (CR)
            {
                case 1:
                    STCR = 3 * CCR;//en cada caso va en precio de lo que vale la comida y bebido, el 3 es el precio
                    break;
                case 2:
                    STCR = 45 * CCR;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    STCR = 375 * CCR;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    STCR = 10 * CCR;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    STCR = 10 * CCR;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    STCR = 15 * CCR;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    STCR = 20 * CCR;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    STCR = 05 * CCR;
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Solo se admiten datos del 1 al 8", "validación de números", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    break;
            }
            TOT = TOT + STCR; 
            this.LBLTOT.Text = TOT.ToString("0.0");

            if (TOT == 1) //aqui quiero que cuando introduzca el 1 que es efectivo me salga el precio total de la compra
            {
                TOT = TOT + STCR;
                this.LBLTOT.Text = TOT.ToString("0.0");
            }
            else
            {
                ST = TOT + STCR * POR - ST;
                this.LBLTOT.Text = ST.ToString("0.0"); // para aplicar el 5%, pero no funciona
            }

            while (RES != "SI" && RES != "NO")//para validar el si y no en el textbox donde se introduce el si y no
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Solo se admiten los datos SI y NO", "validación de datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                if (RES == "NO")
                {
                    this.TXTRESP.Enabled = false;// si le da no ya no dejara introducir mas 
                }

            }
            return;
        }
   
   
    }
```

Comment: Claudia te aconsejo 4 cosas iniciales para que tu programe sea mas facil de realizar: 1- no abrevies el nombre de variables sino es complicado seguirle el hilo, 2- no pongas una logica tan grande dentro de un boton, parti ese boton en pequeños metodos 3- cada vez que tocas el boton para agregar algo, esta reiniciando todas tus variales. 4- Tenes que usar un arreglo para ir guardando tus datos y luego recorres y sumas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dividi tu programa en dos botones y tres cajas de texto, como estas usando windows forms, no es necesario un while para seguir cargando items porque esa carga se da segun el evento Click cada vez que lo presionas. Te saque las variables fuera del boton para que no se inicializen de nuevo cada vez que haces click. Y con un boton cargas comida, con el otro recorres el List y calculas el 5% si uso tarjeta.

```
    private int TotalCuenta = 0;
    private int Porcentaje = 0;
    private List<int> ComidasSubtotal = new List<int>();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int SubTotalComidaRapida = 0; // esta es la variable para el subtotal de comida rapida
        int ST = 0;

        int POR = 005; // es el porcentaje que se le aplicara si la persona elige tarjeta

        string NUM1 = this.TXTCR.Text;
        int CR = int.Parse(NUM1); // esta es para el textbox donde introduzco el numero del 1 al 8(comida y bebida)

        string NUM = this.TXTCCR.Text;
        int CCR = Int16.Parse(NUM); //es para indroducir la cantidad de comida

        switch (CR)
        {
            case 1:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 3 * CCR);//en cada caso va en precio de lo que vale la comida y bebido, el 3 es el precio
                break;
            case 2:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 45 * CCR);
                break;
            case 3:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 375 * CCR);
                break;
            case 4:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 10 * CCR);
                break;
            case 5:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 10 * CCR);
                break;
            case 6:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 15 * CCR);
                break;
            case 7:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 20 * CCR);
                break;
            case 8:
                ComidasSubtotal.Add(SubTotalComidaRapida = 05 * CCR);
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Solo se admiten datos del 1 al 8", "validación de números", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void btn_Calcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
            foreach (int subtotal in ComidasSubtotal)
            {
                TotalCuenta = TotalCuenta + subtotal;
            }
         
           if (txtTipoPago.Text == "1")
           {
              Porcentaje = (TotalCuenta * 5 / 100);
              MessageBox.Show($"Total de cuenta: {TotalCuenta}, el 5% es: {Porcentaje}");
           }
           else
           {
             MessageBox.Show($"Total de cuenta: {TotalCuenta});
           }
    }
```